# How can pyros actually rocket jump?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

I've heard people talk about Pyros being able to rocket-jump in TF2. Since they obviously don't have a rocket launcher, how is this possible?

Comment: I just tracked down a neat youtube clip of this being done. This example was staged, but still pretty awesome. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tmly_W_TtKU

Comment: For more information on actually performing it, see the previous question:
 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3855/what-is-the-timing-to-reliably-reflect-rockets-arrows-and-grenades-in-team-fort

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to have excellent timing and accuracy with reflecting an enemy rocket.  You wait for the rocket to get close to you, timing the reflect to aim it at your own feet and jump and crouch, much like a Soldier would.  Except it's not your rocket.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you reflect a rocket (or a grenade, or arrow for that matter), that projectile becomes "yours" as if you fired it, so technically it *is* your rocket. It's why you get credit for the compression blasted reflections, and why grenades change color when you reflect them back. Sticky Bombs that are already attached to something are the only thing that does not apply to this.

Comment: This also works with the flare gun.